# Take and display the input with structure data type in C language

Tags: c, printf, scanf, structure

This is my very simple struct data type code that doesn't work.

What I want my program to do is to read input from the user and insert the digit into the struct. However, I don't know how to do it since I get just garbage value.

My code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct book {
    char name;
    float price;
    int pages;
};

void main(){
    struct book b1, b2, b3;
    printf("\nEnter neme , prices & pages of 3 books \n");
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b3.name, &b3.price, &b3.pages);

    printf("\nAnd this is what you entered\n");
    printf("%c %f %d\n",b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages);
    printf("%c %f %d\n",b2.name, b2.price, b2.pages);
    printf("%c %f %d\n",b3.name, b3.price, b3.pages);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of input data? Unless the book names are made up by single characters I'm afraid that's causing the garbage value you experience. In fact: 1) `%c` is the format specifier for a single character. 2) Field name can contain a single character. What you need is a _string_: an array of characters big enough to contain the maximum book name size in characters AND the string terminator.

Comment: You have allocated 1 character for `name` in the struct, so it is not possible to store a string in it. For that you need an array of char (and use a string specifier in the `scanf` and `printf` format strkngs.).

Answer (score 0):

Just enter a space before the placeholder for the character in the scanf statements. Like this. The code should run just fine.

```
    scanf(" %c %f %d",&b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
    scanf(" %c %f %d",&b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages);
    scanf(" %c %f %d",&b3.name, &b3.price, &b3.pages);
```

Problem is that when you press enter on the keyboard to move to the next line to provide input to the second scanf statement. "%c" in the second line takes '\n' as the input and this just messes up the order. And remember "%c" or char means name should only consist of 1 character.